# Dropdown with only one possible selection behaves like an on/off switch : is it crossbrowser?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

Working like a switch on Chrome (v27.), FF (v21.), and IE9.
I cannot test on other browsers.

As it doesn't refers to anything else than HTML, I am about to think that it works like this, on any browser. But, I'd like to be sure.

Any help please ?

```
TO CANCEL SELECTED COLOR : 
<select name="transparenceStrips" id="transparenceStrips" size="1" onclick="transpbandeau()">
    <option value="transparent">CLICK HERE</option>
</select>
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iwonder/gVH3n/1/)

Comment: Can you provide and example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: either use http://www.jsfiddle.net to create example or edit your question and add `transpbandeau()` function. Also if you want to test another browsers try online tools like this one https://browserling.com/

Comment: I have no account on jsfiddle, but I will register soon. In fact it behaves like an "off" switch (or "on" as you want!) only. Thanks for the link, I didn't know this before ! But my sources are only local for now, and browserling doesn't seem to be able to work with local files...

Comment: @Edward : jsfiddle made !

Comment: Why would you take a select-tag for this? You can add the onclick attribute to quite any tag (e. g. a-tag or button-tag).

Comment: @m02ph3u5 : why ? probably because I'm very inexperienced with all this ! :-) A button will be great ! Sorry...

Comment: Why can't you use a button like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/gVH3n/3/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not a typical usage of a select, this UI can confuse users; I think it will be better using a button.

Something like:

HTML:

```
COULEUR fond page
<input name="colorFond" id="colorFond" class="color1" value="FFFFFF" size="5" onchange="setBack()">
<br>CANCEL :
<button onclick="transp()">CLICK HERE</button>
```

Code:

```
function transp() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function setBack() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+document.getElementById('colorFond').value;
}
```

Here is a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/gVH3n/3/

Comment: yes,it's much better and simpler ! what I can't understand : locally, my setting color field is getting back to FFFFFF, although on JSFiddle the last chosen color is kept. Although I copy-pasted the JS code. It may be due to other part of code. Nevermind, losing this value is not very important; it would have been better but it's about 1 hour that I'm trying to find out why this happens without any success...

Comment: The only problem that is still there : after having clicked the button that triggers the transp function, the color that was previously selected with jscolor is lost : the field goes to FFFFFF. But it happens only locally : I can't reproduce this on my jsfiddle :(

Comment: I think I don't... locally the JS part is exactly the same that here : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/iwonder/gVH3n/6/)

Comment: It's ok, try to clear your cache; accept this answer and eventually open a new question specifying your new problem.

Comment: cache cleared but it doesn't help. Nevermind... However, thanks for your kind help !

Answer (score 0):

> is it crossbrowser?

It's not cross browser, try testing it on an Android Chrome, you'll find that it tries to open the options list in addition to resetting the background color.

The other answer had given a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, and yes, the other way is much better ! I'm learning things here, and it's much better that fiddling alone :-) thanks !